Migrating apache http client 5 from 5.3 to 5.4 trust all hosts and certificates deprecation replacement
I have upgraded from apache http client 5.3.x to 5.4.x.
The below code works fine
var sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadTrustMaterial(null, TrustAllStrategy.INSTANCE)
        .build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnSocketFactory = 
    SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.create()
        .setHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
        .setSslContext(sslContext)
        .build();

var connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnSocketFactory)
        .build();

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
        .build();

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://mms.nw.ru/");
HttpHost host = RoutingSupport.determineHost(httpGet);
ClassicHttpResponse response = client.executeOpen(host, httpGet, null);
Assertions.assertEquals(200, response.getCode());

But the SSLConnectionSocketFactory class and setSSLSocketFactory method of PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder became deprecated.
I have changed the code to
var sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadTrustMaterial(null, TrustAllStrategy.INSTANCE)
        .build();

var tlsStrategy = ClientTlsStrategyBuilder.create()
        .setSslContext(sslContext)
        .setHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
        .build();

var connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
        .setTlsSocketStrategy((TlsSocketStrategy) tlsStrategy)
        .build();

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
        .build();

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://mms.nw.ru/");
HttpHost host = RoutingSupport.determineHost(httpGet);
ClassicHttpResponse response = client.executeOpen(host, httpGet, null);
Assertions.assertEquals(200, response.getCode());

It throws javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No name matching mms.nw.ru found cause java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching mms.nw.ru found.
What is wrong ?

This question is similar to: HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory() method not found. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@aled My question was not about missing but replacement deprecation of ConnectionManagerBuilder.setSSLSocketFactory method. Thanks for suggestion.

As of version 5.4 HttpClient makes use of built-in hostname verification provided by JSSE. In order to disable hostname verification completely initialize the TLS strategy in your code the following way
var tlsStrategy = new DefaultClientTlsStrategy(
  sslContext, 
  HostnameVerificationPolicy.CLIENT, 
  NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

